# Why does expected values only occur when I run my code in debug mode, but breaks when I aren't debugging, and how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I am having a fat headache session with this following code, and was wondering if anyone can help me.

I have a view called Details.aspx, residing in a folder called project. Inside the details view, I have the following key code snippets which is causing me to get a headache.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Global_ProjectID = <%:Model.ProjectID%>; //Gets the project ID from Project Table In model
</script>
```

Inside a form tag (`<form action="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Issue/AddIssue") %>" method="post">`) resides the following code:

```
        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="submit small" value="Add Issue" onclick="return IssueSubmitForm()"/>
            or <a href="">cancel</a></p>
```

And then I have some more Javascript to talk to my controller called IssueController, with the method called AddIssue

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var PostBackUrl = "<%:ResolveUrl("~/Issue/AddIssue")%>";

    //Front-end Validation here

    function IssueSubmitForm() {
        var PostBackData = {
            Title: $("input[name=Title]").val(),
            Details: $("textarea[name=Details]").val(),
            ReportedBy: $("input[name=ReportedBy]").val(),
            Priority: $("select[name=Priority]").val(),
            ProjectID: Global_ProjectID
        };

        $.post(PostBackUrl,PostBackData);
    }
</script>
```

This gets the information entered into the form (from various web controls), and the value from the Global_ProjectID

In my controller, the following method is the one that is called from my javascript

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddIssue(Models.Issue issue)
    {
        Models.Issue newIssue = new Models.Issue()
        {
            Title = issue.Title,
            DateLogged = DateTime.Now,
            Status = 0,
            ReportedBy = issue.ReportedBy,
            Priority = issue.Priority,
            ProjectID = issue.ProjectID,
        };
        return View("SomeOtherViewSomewhere");
    }
```

Now here is the weird part.

All my fields (like title, reportedby etc.) gets filled as it should, i.e. It actually contains the value I expect it to contain- the data I filled into my form. ProjectID always happens to be null, when it should actually contain an integer value.

When I activated the debugger on my javascript in my browser, I saw that ProjectID did get populated, and in the event I added the following code `Alert(Global_ProjectID);`, it also gave me a popup with the value I needed.

However, the moment I run these code segments without debugging, ProjectID is always null. It is sadly a value that I must use recurringly, and null simply won't do

What can I do to fix this code? I had other programmers look at it, and they were also just as stumped as I were.

Comment: tried a million things now. If I remove the Action from the form tag, it doesn't execute the controller method, and sends back the same page I am on. If I leave in the alert before $.post , it displays the value I need ALL THE TIME. When I save the values to the database , it randomly decides when that value appears or is null (for some odd reason)

Comment: and again, here comes another tumbleweed. I can smoke it :<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into [Javascript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) - JS doesn't always behave in the way you expect with regard to the order in which variables and functions are initialised.

You can probably work around the issue by adjusting your `IssueSubmitForm` function to accept `ProjectID` as a parameter, and use `onclick="return IssueSubmitForm(Global_ProjectID)"` on your submit button...

Or even better, remove the inline function call and bind a submit event after the page has loaded in the  `$(document).ready()` event.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you. It turned out that there was some javascript kicking up some bad results. I just forgot to check on stackoverflow for answers. I did pretty much the same as you suggested as far as I remember. 

Thanks